# How to get access from localhost:8080 to service using nginx-ingress?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to access nginx on pod using localhost:8080 as uri, not minikube ip

```
  apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: nginx-service
    spec:
      selector:
        app: webserver
      ports:
        - port: 80
          targetPort: 80
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is for development/debug purpose.
So if you can't use port-forward option as @arghya-sadhu suggested, then you'll just have to map your domain to your ip.

I can see that's what you're trying to do in your nginx deployment with those lines :

```
spec:
  hostAliases:
  - ip: 192.168.99.101
    hostnames:
    - localhost
```

However, this will not affect your host. In order to map localhost to the minikube ip, you'll have to edit your `/etc/hosts` file. Below is the line you need to add :

```
192.168.99.101    localhost
#127.0.0.1    localhost <-- this line needs to be commented
```

Be sure to comment the existing line with localhost

Comment: Is there a best practice how to manage /etc/hosts file in container?

Comment: The modification on `/etc/hosts` is to be done on your host, not the container ! You have to do it on the host from which the request will be made. So not the container nor the minikube vm.

Comment: It works with adding any name to host in ingress except localhost)
127.0.0.1 localhost is commented

Comment: Ah.. yes.. localhost is quite an exception as you would guess... You **have** to use it ? It can't be anything else ?

Comment: I have to use localhost.

Comment: So you *have* to use localhost from your host, and make it point to your minikube VM and pass through an ingress that point to localhost... what sort of constraint do you have ? Generally speaking, using `localhost` is for debug/development thus a simple port forwarding do the trick... I mean the domain `localhost` is a bit particular and that's why it's so complicated (i don't even know if there *is* a solution)